# Why does IF statement fail when OR || is used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

My Ruby if statement fails when the or operator is used.

```
<% if @body_id == 'plants' || 'trees' %>
   <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<% end %>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "fails", you get an error? If yes please include the stack trace. If it is unexpected behaviour, please add what is your actual and expected behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

You cant use `||` like that, id do `['plants', 'trees'].includes? @body_id` instead.

Comment: `%w[plants trees]` all hail rubocop

Comment: @dezman - Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be?

```
<% if @body_id == 'plants' || @body_id == 'trees' %>
```